# "Type Mismatch"error when trying to use nested formula in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to calculate the value using below formula but getting an error message as "Type Mismatch"

```
Dim exp_comp As Integer

Sheets("Dashboard").Select
Range("M2").Select
Selection.Formula = "=DAYS(H2,TODAY())"

exp_comp = WorksheetFunction.Product(("H" & row / "L" & row), "M2")
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("J" & row).Value = exp_comp
```

Comment: What do you mean by row in your code line worksheetfunction.Product , do you have row variable defined somewhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The division should be like this:

```
Range("H" & 1)/ Range("L" & 1)
```

1 is instead of the `row`, considering that it is defined somewhere.